# push down div when hidden div comes to play?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I got a set of radio buttons which are connected with set of hidden div's. onClick with javascript they should be activated and show a selected by radio button div content, I want this div to be place in a specific location on a page and push down everything what's bellow down to the bottom ?

I tried to give my div properties like: overflow: hidden; - but it does'n work for me for some reason?

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: Why not create a jsfiddle or at least post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post code, so I'm using generic example code here.

The HTML:

```
<input type='radio' name='exampleRadio' id='firstRadio'> First 
<input type='radio' name='exampleRadio' id='secondRadio'> Second 
<input type='radio' name='exampleRadio' id='thirdRadio' checked> None

<div id='firstHiddenDiv'>Content Here</div>
<div id='secondHiddenDiv'>More Content Here</div>

<div>Content to be pushed down here</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#firstHiddenDiv, #secondHiddenDiv { display:none; }
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#firstRadio").click(function() {
    $("#secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
    $("#firstHiddenDiv").show("slow");
  });
  $("#secondRadio").click(function() {
    $("#firstHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
    $("#secondHiddenDiv").show("slow");
  });
  $("#thirdRadio").click(function() {
    $("#firstHiddenDiv, #secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow"); 
  });
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/2syzQ/).

The explanation:

Once the page loads, the jQuery sets event listeners on the radio buttons.  Once one is clicked, it uses `hide()` to remove the `div` that should be hidden.  It uses the `show()` to then display the correct `div`.  Using `show("slow")` provides the animation effect.  You can remove the `"slow"` if you want the effect to be immediate.

Answer (score 0):

This an Example of toggling a elements visibility using pure javascript. You can also do it within few line of using library like jQuery.

Html :

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="hiddenRadio">
<input type="radio" name=radiobtn1 value="1" >one
<input type="radio" name=radiobtn2 value="2" checked>two
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var radioDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenRadio');
radioDiv.style.display='none';

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  //If you only want to display not to 
  // Toggle then : radioDiv.style.display='block'; 
  if(radioDiv.style.display != 'block') {
return radioDiv.style.display='block';
  }
  radioDiv.style.display = 'none';

});
```